# GridView creating context menu with filter

Tags: android, listview, gridview, contextmenu, adapter

I currently have a grid view with custom array adapter and filter. I am trying to create a context menu based on a long click on a gridview item. However, before adding the filter, I would state which item had been pressed depending on its position, now, when the items are filtered, the positions change so any action taken uses the wrong resource/selects the wrong item. Any idea round this?

Here is my gridview initialization:

```
final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    aAdpt = new shareadapter(planetsList, this);
    gridview.setAdapter(aAdpt);
    gridview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    this.registerForContextMenu(gridview);
```

Here is my onClickListener (As an example of how I would normally obtain the filtered item to use in an activity/intent:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Planet link = (Planet) gridview.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(ShareActivity.this,
                    ShareActivitySecond.class);
            i.putExtra("IdImgFull", link.getIdImgFull());
            i.putExtra("IdImgShare", link.getIdImgShare());
            startActivity(i);
            // startSecondActivity(position);
        }
    });
```

And here is my create context menu, as you can see it depends on position and I'm not sure how to add the variable int 
    link.getIdImgShare()

into it.

```
    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.shareactivity, menu);
}

    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    int IndexSelected = info.position;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.share:
        shareMethod(IndexSelected);
        return true;
    case R.id.save:
        saveMethod(IndexSelected);
        return true;
    default:
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it!

Called my adapter and array within the onContextItemSelected, and from there was able to set the variable to the action. Crucial two lines are:

```
Planet planet = aAdpt.getItem(aInfo.position);
int IdImgShare = planet.getIdImgShare();
```

Full section:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo aInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    Planet planet = aAdpt.getItem(aInfo.position);
    int IdImgShare = planet.getIdImgShare();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.share:
        shareMethod(IdImgShare);
        return true;
    case R.id.save:
        saveMethod(IdImgShare);
        return true;
    default:
        return true;
    }
}
```